# I need insert 2 records in differents tables,

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I need to insert 2 records into 2 different tables. The problem is that the two records will be with the same Id.
For example :

I have my Mannto table, with its IdMan and oters fields. I also have my Service table, with its IdServ.

What can I do to make this one equal? I am using Postgre. The Id of the Mannto table is serial and I need to use that one as a Foreign key in the Service table

I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
Insert into Mannto ( idMan, field 1 field2 ...etc) 
            values ( default, 'f1', 'f2'...etc)

Insert into Service ( idServ, fkMannto, field1...etc) 
             values (default, (in this part I need the same ManntoId called idMan), 'f1')
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO Mannto ( field1, field2 ...etc) VALUES ( 'f1', 'f2'...etc)
  RETURNING idMan;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html

Answer (score 1):

When field idMan uses a sequence to create a new value, you can refer to this value in the next INSERT using [CURRVAL()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html):

```
BEGIN; -- start transaction
      INSERT INTO Mannto ( idMan, field 1 field2 ...etc) 
        VALUES ( default, 'f1', 'f2'...etc);   
      INSERT INTO Service ( idServ, fkMannto, field1...etc) 
        VALUES (default, currval('name_of_the_sequence') , 'f1');
COMMIT; -- commit both inserts
```

Comment: and for delete should be the same ?
  BEGIN;
        
        DELETE FROM servicio WHERE pkmantenimiento = ?;
        DELETE FROM mantenimiento WHERE idmantenimiento =  CURRVAL('name_of_the_sequence');
        COMMIT;

Comment: No, that won't work. There is no need for either, just create a foreign key on idmantenimiento that references to pkmantenimiento and the DELETE in mantenimeinte will be done automatically by the database when you delete a record in the table servicio.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best solution but you could use a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MannToTrigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON MannTo
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertService();
```

Fetch your MannTo inserted last code and throw the procedure after each insert.

Comment: I tried that one, but had some problems, but thanks a lot anyway :) for answer